# What is the difference between COUNT(*) AND COUNT([attribute]) in the following scenario?

Tags: group-by, count

I have the following tables :

```
DEPARTMENT

department_id
department_name
manager_id
location_id
```

and

```
EMPLOYEES

employee_id
first_name
last_name
email
phone_number
hire_date
job_id
salary
commission_pct
manager_id
department_id
```

I want to count the number of employees working in each department.

I have used the following query :

```
SELECT department_name, count(*)
FROM departments d LEFT OUTER JOIN employees e
ON e.department_id = d.department_id
GROUP BY department_name;
```

But in the results the employee which has no employees does not show up in the results. I want the number of employees to show up as 0. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

> In terms of the speed:

As I know that both the queries (select count(*) or Select Count(id)) are using same execution plan, so should use same amount of CPU as long as blocks are fetched from either buffer pool or from disk not mix.

> In terms of the result, and in your case:

- if you said count(*), then it will count the row even if you don't have employees since you are making left join.
- if you said count(employee_id), then this will only count the rows "which are exists", means not the null rows.. *I think this is what you need to have 0 for your case*
- If you want to mention the field and you want to count it even if there's no row you have to say count(NVL(employee_id, 123)) while 123 is any value in case null

Comment: Ok, understood, is there any other way to write this query without a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: Yes, try this: SELECT DEPARTMENT_NAME,
       (SELECT COUNT (EMPLOYEE_ID)
          FROM EMPLOYEES
         WHERE EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_ID)
          AS COUNT_OF_EMPS
  FROM DEPARTMENTS

Answer (score 1):

> I want the number of employees to show up as 0. How do I do that?

```
select d.department_name,
       count(e.employee_id)
from departments d 
  left outer join employees e
    on e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_name;
```

`count(*)` will count all rows and `count(e.employee_id)` counts all non null values.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02c61/1)

> But in the results the employee which has no employees does not show
>   up in the results.

I have no idea why you see that. The query you have returns a count of 1 for the departments without employees.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02c61/3)